# facing issue to make the build

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

[image]

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}
```

react-native version -

```
"react-native": "0.64.1",
```

JDK version is - 17.0.1

i am trying to run the application

Comment: React Native project is unable to find the dependency manager. This can happen if the project is not properly configured or if the dependency manager is not installed.